# Having trouble when implementing ReactJS pagination control

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am receiving the maximum size of the pages in every click handler of the paging (for example when clicking 2 I am receiving 4 as a handler parameter). What's wrong with this code?

**UPDATE**

```
class PagingControl extends React.Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {pageNumber:0, pageSize:20, totalPages:0};
        this.handlePageChanged = this.handlePageChanged.bind(this);
    }

    handlePageChanged(pageNumber){
        this.setState({pageNumber: pageNumber})
        this.props.handlePageChanged(pageNumber);
    }

    render(){

        const pages = [];
        for(var pageNumber=0 ; pageNumber<this.state.totalPages ; pageNumber ++){
            var opts={}
            if(pageNumber == this.state.pageNumber){
                opts['className'] = 'active';
            }
            pages.push(<li onClick={() => this.handlePageChanged(pageNumber)} {...opts}><a href="#">{pageNumber + 1}</a></li>);
        }

        return (<ul className="pagination pagination-lg">{pages}</ul>);
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd need to bind your pageNumber to your handler. Like this: `onClick={() => this.handlePageChanged.bind(this, pageNumber)}`

Comment: @Chris Thanks, I already defined my handlePageChanged handler and want to reuse that. Updating the decription

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, just changed `var pageNumber=0` in for loop to be `let pageNumber=0`